# Select date from another table

Tags: mysql, php

I really need your help. Please help me out to get this to work.

I have these two tables, the `relation` between them is the `user_id`. I accomplished to select who I follow and to display their images into my wall. However, I have this strange issue: the photos are sorted by `DESC` as i want, but they are sorted by the `user_id`. This means that whoever I follow first, their image will be sorted first by `DESC`.

I tried almost every possible way to get the photos to be sorted base on `DESC` newest photo as the top, but I couldn't. Here are my tables and i'll show you every possible thing I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `about` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `down` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `followers` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `following` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
}
```

### One

followers_photo.php, where I retrieve the `following id` from:

```
$the_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'");
$tuser=mysql_fetch_array($the_user);
$tu_id = $tuser['id'];

$followers = mysql_query("SELECT distinct follow.*    
 FROM follow JOIN photos ON (follow.followers  = $tu_id)
order by photos.date DESC");
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
```

- index.php  which i display the images here.

> while($uim = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){     $i_id =
>   $uim['following']; $followers_image = mysql_query("SELECT distinct 
>   photos.*  FROM photos JOIN follow ON (photos.user_id  = $i_id)  GROUP
>   BY RAND() order by date DESC");

---

The above is working, but as I mentioned it sorts the images based on date `DESC` and the `user_id` which I don't want. I want it to stop sorting the image based on the `user_id`

### Two

followers_photo.php

```
    $the_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'");
$tuser=mysql_fetch_array($the_user);
$isuser = mysql_num_rows($the_user);

$tu_id = $tuser['id'];
$tu_name =$tuser ['username'];
////users whos following Me
$followers = mysql_query(" SELECT distinct follow.* FROM photos join  follow on  follow.followers = photos.user_id WHERE follow.followers = $tu_id order by photos.date DESC");
//
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
```

---

index.php

```
    while($uim = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){
$i_id = $uim['following'];
$followers_image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos  WHERE user_id = '$i_id' order by date DESC ");
```

The above does the same as in the first step. Could anyone point me to the right way? Sort the photos from the people I follow based on `date DESC`, who posts last comes first. Thanks guys, I appreciate your help a lot. And sorry for my bad English.

### Update

now with the solution that vegatripy give , images are duplicating and not order as wanted.
on left is what is showing now. what i want is to sort as the right image. any ideas? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cod6z.jpg

### Solved

```
    $followers = mysql_query("SELECT PHOTOs.IMG, follow.followers, follow.following, photos.date,photos.img,photos.likes,photos.down,photos.id,photos.about
FROM FOLLOW
JOIN PHOTOs ON ( PHOTOs.USER_ID = FOLLOW.FOLLOWING ) 
WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOWERS =31
ORDER BY PHOTOs.DATE DESC");
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
while($fimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){
$i_id = $fimage['following'];
$disimg = $fimage['img'];
$disid = $fimage['id'];
$distime = $fimage['date'];
$i_like=$fimage['likes'];
$i_unlike=$fimage['down'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the `JOIN` with the missing `WHERE` clause in your sentences (and that's why you used the `DISTINCT`, because there's no *join condition* at all and you had repeated rows)

> ```
> $followers = mysql_query("SELECT distinct follow.*    
>  FROM follow JOIN photos ON (follow.followers  = $tu_id)
> order by photos.date DESC");
> ```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT distinct follow.*
FROM follow, photos WHERE (follow.followers  = $tu_id)
order by photos.date DESC");
```

That join is giving you the whole cartesian product (`FROM follow JOIN photos`) where column `follow.followers =  $tu_id`, that includes not *truly* joined rows between "follow" and "photos" tables . To discard rows, you'll need the `where` clause AFTER the *join codition*.

Anyway, you're mixing things a little bit. I've analyzed your code several times and I don't get why you are joining "photos" with "follow" tables, when you're selecting columns and using the where condition from just one of them.

I'm going to set an example of what you're trying to do. Just the SQL meaningful stuff. I'll let the PHP to you.
These are the tables USERS, PHOTO and FOLLOW

```
USERS:
ID      USERNAME
--      --------
01      John
02      Smith
03      Rambo

PHOTO: (just the relevant columns)
ID      IMG     DATE            USER_ID  
--      -----   -----------     ------- 
01      a.jpg   01-02-2013      03  (Rambo)
02      b.jpg   30-07-2013      03  (Rambo)
03      c.jpg   04-04-2012      02  (Smith)
04      d.jog   04-04-2013      01  (John)

FOLLOW:
ID      FOLLOWERS   FOLLOWING
--      --          --
01      01          02      (John is following Smith)
02      01          03      (John is following Rambo)
03      02          01      (Smith is following John)
04      03          01      (Rambo is following John)
05      02          03      (Smith is following Rambo)
```

With this set up, we want to display the images from the users of a given username is following, order by date of image. 
So, the given username is "John". That is ID "01". 
If we just need the images from the people that John is following, then:

```
SELECT PHOTO.IMG 
FROM FOLLOW JOIN PHOTO ON (PHOTO.USER_ID = FOLLOW.FOLLOWING) 
WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOWERS = 01
ORDER BY PHOTO.DATE DESC;
```

We are joining "Photo.User_ID" with "Follow.following", order by date desc. This will make a temp table like:

```
PHOTO.ID    PHOTO.IMG   PHOTO.DATE  PHOTO.USER_ID   FOLLOW.ID   FOLLOW.FOLLOWERS    FOLLOW.FOLLOWING
--          -----       ----------  -------         --          --                  --
02          b.jpg       30-07-2013  03  (Rambo)     02          01                  03      (John is following Rambo)
04          d.jog       04-04-2013  01  (John)      04          03                  01      (Rambo is following John)
04          d.jog       04-04-2013  01  (John)      03          02                  01      (Smith is following John)
01          a.jpg       01-02-2013  03  (Rambo)     02          01                  03      (John is following Rambo)
03          c.jpg       04-04-2012  02  (Smith)     01          01                  02      (John is following Smith)
```

Then the `WHERE` clause will select only those rows where the follower is the user_id we want (01). That's:

```
PHOTO.ID    PHOTO.IMG   PHOTO.DATE  PHOTO.USER_ID   FOLLOW.ID   FOLLOW.FOLLOWERS    FOLLOW.FOLLOWING
--          -----       ----------  -------         --          --                  --
02          b.jpg       30-07-2013  03  (Rambo)     02          01                  03      (John is following Rambo)
01          a.jpg       01-02-2013  03  (Rambo)     02          01                  03      (John is following Rambo)
03          c.jpg       04-04-2012  02  (Smith)     01          01                  02      (John is following Smith)
```

So as John we will see 2 photos from Rambo and 1 from Smith. Ordered by date.

Hope this help you.

Comment: first thanks for your reply and for explanation that you gave even my lecturers never did. i did tried your code, but now i'm getting an error where i want to select the following id form index.php so i can display the images. i tried to post that code in the index.php where selecting the photos but other stuff got missy. could you please help me out. thanks

Comment: i have added the column follow.following after the photo.img in the follower_photo.php . it did duplicates the images tho. but i ran your code in mysql and it actually sort them as i want but with duplicates and base on the user_id as well, which i dont want, you can image if i upload an image my and all my images will be showing also. which i dont want. if i post an image it show at top. if other post it show at top while the others images will be sorted by their date. is it possible?

Comment: MAN i did it. omfg i can't believe loool three days stuck on this :D here is how i did and all because of u are a genius.
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT PHOTOs.IMG, follow.followers, follow.following, photos.date,photos.img,photos.likes,photos.down,photos.id,photos.about
FROM FOLLOW
JOIN PHOTOs ON ( PHOTOs.USER_ID = FOLLOW.FOLLOWING ) 
WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOWERS =31
ORDER BY PHOTOs.DATE DESC");
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
while($fimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){
$i_id = $fimage['following'];

Comment: i replace my whole code with this one and it works. i deleted fetching the photos by selecting from photos where ...... and it worked lol. thanks dude.